# How safe is the encryption offered by Mac OS X's Finder?

Tags: disk-encryption, macos, truecrypt, usb-drive

If you plug in a USB drive, open it in Finder and right-click the Finder window, you get the option to encrypt the drive.

[image: Screenshot from howtogeek.com]

What methods does Finder use to encrypt the drive and how safe is it actually? Is it a smarter idea to use the TrueCrypt 7.1a version instead?

PS: I am using the current version of Mac OS X 10.11.1 "El Capitan".

Comment: TrueCrypt has been deprecated for nearly a year and a half now. Get off it.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use TrueCrypt since it is no longer actively maintained, therefore, no longer safe to use. Truecrypts own website states **“WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues”** 

I would recommend using Apple's Built In Feature it is safe and secure, and of course, your files are as secured as the password you use to secure them. As far as the algorithms used to encrypt your password, gives you two options, choose the more secure option is somewhat slower encrypting/decrypting, of course you will only notice the difference with large files. You can choose 128-bit or 256-bit AES algorithms. The cipher AES 128-bit and/or 256-bit are both very secure TSL/SSL use it to encrypt end-to-end traffic across the Internet, it is considered among the top ciphers ***(Although NSA has categorized this to be in Grade-B, and their recommendation is to use 256-bit keys for encryption)***. Anyway to answer your question most third party programs today offer AES among other options to encrypt your data, therefore, I don't see any reason why you shouldn't use the built in feature for encryption.

Comment: It's correct, that TrueCrypt is no longer being maintained, but independent code audits recently proved the last version of TrueCrypt (7.1a) to be secure. I don't know of any audits of Mac OS X's built-in encryption implementation. I don't doubt that AES is secure but the implementation is what I am curious about.

Comment: @eof0100 the question isn't about which ciphers OS X supports, but rather whether or not their *implementation* of those ciphers contains bugs. Apple being Apple will never release their source code for audit / review, so I think comfreak is looking for any 3rd-party information about its trustworthiness.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth that's what I tried to express in my comment. Thanks for clarifying it!

Comment: Will you only want to use the USB key on a Mac, or would you ever take it out and use it with a Wide down PC too?

Comment: Do you have anything to support the assertion that 'Apple's Built in Feature is safe and secure'?

Comment: @R15 No, I guess I don't have any evidence to support the assertion that Apples Built in Feature is secure. I guess you just have to trust it. I mean when we all used truecrypt, before the audit, we had to trust it was secure and had no backdoors. But you are right I have zero evidence.

Comment: I was rather hoping you had found something!

Comment: I know this is an older thread but since the original answer was submitted Apple has substantially changed their stance re: Transparency and Cryptography.  They've submitted their source code for FIPS approval and have [released the source code of their implementations](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/10/apple-crypto-open-source): corecryptography Common Crypto and Security Framework. Read more at [Apple Security Page](https://developer.apple.com/security/).